# Column Menu kendo UI

Tags: menu, header, grid, right-click

I have a grid with column menu. Now, i want to disable sorting from the column menu because it is enabled on the each column clickable header. Can someone help me? 
And if there is any way to customize the column menu (add new options column size or something like that) and to be able to call the column menu on the right click on the mouse instead in its default position(next to the column name)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the mvc wrapper you can do like this

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Asyst.Models.AGENT>()
            .ColumnMenu(columns => columns.Sortable(false))
```